# Проблемы со звуком при смене камер

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

В игре, есть фоновая музыка, которая играет со старта уровня.

Вот она:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А также есть звук, который проигрывается лишь при заставке "Game Over".

Вот он:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что, собственно, я делаю?

**Скрипт HealthManager:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HealthManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int maxPlayerHealth;

    public static int playerCurHealth;

    public Game gameManager;

    //переменная главного меню
    public string mainMenu;

    public GameObject gameOverScreen;

    public Player player;

    public float waitAfterGameOver;

    public GameObject musicBack;

    public GameObject musicGameOver;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        //musicGameOver.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        playerCurHealth = maxPlayerHealth;

        gameManager = FindObjectOfType<Game>();

        player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (playerCurHealth <= 0)
        {  
            //playerCurHealth = 0;

            gameOverScreen.SetActive(true);

            player.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            musicBack.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            musicGameOver.gameObject.SetActive(true);


        }

        if (gameOverScreen.activeSelf) 
        {
            waitAfterGameOver -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (waitAfterGameOver < 0) 
        {

            Application.LoadLevel("mainMenu");
        }

        if (playerCurHealth > maxPlayerHealth)
        {
            playerCurHealth = maxPlayerHealth;
        }
    }

    public void TakeLife()
    {
        playerCurHealth--;
    }

    public void FullHealth()
    {
        playerCurHealth = maxPlayerHealth;
    }

}
```

То есть, стоит звук Гейм Овера в положение выкл. (да, я не понимаю до конца, что даёт снятая галочка (где-то в соседней теме это оговаривалось)). При появления заставки "Game Over" музыка переводится в `SetActive(true);`, затем нас возвращает в главное меню и в чём собственно вопрос... Когда переключаю там камеру (через кнопки и SetActive), то при повторном проигрыше и заставке "Game Over" выскакивает вот такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так? Чего я не знаю? Как сделать, чтобы при разных положениях моей камеры звук проигрывался одинаково в обоих случаях? Что означает сообщение об ошибке и как её исправить?

***UPDATE:***

К комментарию ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Заметил только что такую странность, что при появлении GameOverScreen первая камера всё ещё работает (как и положено), при второй камере иная ситуация. Уже на GameOverScreen она не работает (не активна, снята галочка с объекта(как правильно сказать?)).*

**Скрипт SwitchCameras:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SwitchCameras : MonoBehaviour {

    public Game theGame;

    public static int numberOfCamera;

    private void Start() {

        theGame = FindObjectOfType<Game>();
        //theGame.cam1.enabled = true;
        //theGame.cam2.enabled = false;
    }

    public void Switch1() {

        numberOfCamera = 1;
        //theGame.cam1.enabled = !theGame.cam1.enabled;
        //theGame.cam2.enabled = !theGame.cam2.enabled;
    }

    public void Switch2() {

        numberOfCamera = 2;
        //theGame.cam1.enabled = !theGame.cam1.enabled;
        //theGame.cam2.enabled = !theGame.cam2.enabled;
    }
}
```

**Скрипт Game:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    // материал стен
    public Material wallMaterial;

    // набранные очки
    //public static int points;

    // количество стен в уровне
    public int countWals = 10;

    //private string _pointsString;
    //private int _lastPonts = -1;

    //игровой объект - текщий чекпоинт
    public GameObject currentCheckpoint;

    //штрафные очки за смерть
    public int pointPenaltyOnDeath;

    //наш игрок
    private Player player;

    public HealthManager healthManager;


    //камеры для переключения
    public Camera cam1;
    public Camera cam2; 

    // генерируем уровень при загрузке сцены
    public void Awake()
    {
        if (SwitchCameras.numberOfCamera == 1) 
        {
            cam1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            cam2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        if (SwitchCameras.numberOfCamera == 2) 
        {
            cam1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            cam2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        // обнуляем очки
        //points = 0;

        // генерируем уровень
        GenerateLevel();

        // ставим первую еду
        Food.GenerateNewFood();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        //игрок это объект со скриптом Player
        player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();

        healthManager = FindObjectOfType<HealthManager> ();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        // обновление отображаемого текста очков только при их изменении
        //if (_lastPonts == points) return;

        //_lastPonts = points;
        // форматируем очки в формате четырех цифр, начинающихся с нулей
        //_pointsString = "Score: "+ points.ToString("0000");
    }


    // отрисовка набранных очков
    //public void OnGUI()
    //{
        //GUI.color = Color.yellow;
    //  GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 20, 200, 20), _pointsString ?? "");
    //}

    // функция генерации уровня
    private void GenerateLevel()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < countWals; i++)
        {
            // создаем куб
            GameObject wall = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            // называем его "Wall"
            wall.name = "Wall";
            // увеличиваем его габариты
            wall.transform.localScale = new Vector3(2,2,2);

            // расставляем его так, чтобы координаты были не в центре игрового поля
            var pos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-40, 41), 0, Random.Range(-40, 41));
            while (Mathf.Abs(pos.x) < 10 || Mathf.Abs(pos.z) < 10)
            {
                pos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-40, 41), 0, Random.Range(-40, 41));
            }
            wall.transform.position = pos;
            // и назначаем материал
            wall.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = wallMaterial;
        }

    }

    // функция восскрешения(респауна) игрока
    public void RespawnPlayer()
    {

        ScoreManager.AddPoints (-pointPenaltyOnDeath);



        player.enabled = false;

        //чтобы видеть в логе, что респаун прошёл успешно
        Debug.Log ("Player Respawn");
        //перемещаем игрока в местоположение чекпоинта
        player.transform.position = currentCheckpoint.transform.position;

        player.enabled = true;

    }
}
```

---

[Ссылка на проект](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9hjq6t8odsltyet/Snake3D%20v.0.0.2.rar?dl=0)

Comment: Нет слушателя, говорит. Нужно чтоб хотя б один был....видимо на одной камере есть `AudioListener`, а у другой нет... и включаете как раз камеру, где нет данного компонента

Comment: @АлексейШиманский UPDATE

Comment: Шо то как-то сложно)) где-то вы в каком-нибудь скрипте `listener` делаете `enabled  = false` ...надо вам посмотреть в проекте получше, где вы `false` присваиваете...  Кстати, как интересно у вас `SwitchCamers` работают. мне кажется этот скрипт не будет находить `FindObjectOfType<Game>()`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский почему?

Comment: Ну Game у вас в Game)) а скрипт в Menu

Comment: @АлексейШиманский возможно я что-то и напутал или забыл убрать, но мне казалось, что таким образом можно таскать переменные, функции из скрипта гейма в скрипт меню.